# Algorithm for 'flooding' an area

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, flood-fill

I need to inspect all the cells of a grid that my game character can reach. To do this, I need to start from the characters position and then 'flood' the area to find all the reachable cells (cells that are not blocked by a wall, for example).

In this drawing, the player is `P` and the walls that block the player are represented by `X`. I need to inspect all cells in the area in which the player is positioned.

```
X X X X X X X X
X     X X     X
X P     X X X X
X X         X X
X X   X X X X X
X X X X X X X X
```

Is there any nice iterative algorithm for doing this? Currently I'm doing this recursively.

Comment: @sch Nothing. I'd just like to know if there's an iterative alternative.

Comment: I think the recursive solution is the best.

Comment: There are a number of algorithms on Wikipedia, surely one will work for you: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill

Answer (score 2):

Put the initial position in a queue.

```
while queue is not empty
    remove an entry from the queue
    add all reachable neighbours not yet marked to the queue (unless they are already in)
    mark position as reachable
end while
```

Comment: This is not iterative, you just replaced the recursion with an explicit stack.

Comment: And that is not iterative how?

Comment: @wildplasser: This can simply be implemented very efficiently with a FIFO stack/queue. Stack and queue are very closely related anyway.

Comment: @nightcracker could you please elaborate in how far the above is not iterative?

Comment: @DanielFischer: I find this hard to explain, what you did was replace the callstack of a recursive function with an explicit "to-do list". I'll remove the downvote because it seems very disputed, but I still think it's like this.

Comment: @nightcracker the approach is iterative and this is in fact breadth-first search which I also think is the best solution for this problem.

Comment: @izomorphius: No, it's one of the worst, depending on the situation. Because it's breadth-first every _reachable_ "pixel" gets checked 4 times if it's a neighbour. The optimal approach checks _every_ pixel once. This can be bad performing on very large areas (with only a small part getting flood-filled), but the algorithm can be applied iteratively to a quadtree representing the original area, solving that problem.

Comment: Yes, that's what I did. I have seen that mentioned as a technique to transform recursive algorithms to iterative ones in many places. Since the function doesn't call itself (directly or indirectly), it's not a recursive implementation of the algorithm by the definition of recursion I'm familiar with. Thanks for explaining (also for removing the downvote, but two points - meh), but if you could elaborate more or refer to an elaboration, that would be great, since I don't yet fully understand your point.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [BFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search). Represent the area in a rectangular grid. Each cell of the grid is a vertex in the graph and there is an edge between two vertices if and only if both cells are non-walls and the cells are neighbouring.